# Extend connection in cloudfoundry for more than 30 seconds

Tags: chat, cloud-foundry

I am trying to develop a chat application in java and have deployed a sample application that uses RabbitMQ and Comet.
I have been able to send and receive messages from the bounded RabbitMQ service.

The problem occurs when I try to pool the queue for messages when there are no pending messages to deliver.

Instead of waiting for a new message and keep the connection open, I am getting 504 error code.

This I believe is due to the Cloud Foundry condition that the request has to be responded within 30 sec.

As I want to keep the connection open until I have a message to deliver to the client, is there any way I can overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

The CloudFoundry.com Router has a 30-second timeout which results in the 504 error. Long connections may be kept open on a 30-second rolling window, meaning that an application must send data every 30 seconds to prevent the 504 error from occurring. For example, here is a simple node.js app that sends a response to the client every 25 seconds, for a total of 75 seconds:

```
var http = require('http');
var host = process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 4567;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    res.write('1');
    setTimeout(function() {
      res.write('2');
      setTimeout(function() {
        res.write('3');
        res.end();
      }, 25000);
    }, 25000);
  }, 25000);

}).listen(port,host)

console.log('Server running at http://' + host + ':' + port);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However even if we manage to keep the 30 sec window rolling it does have its implication on the mobile apps especially in terms of battery usage.  Is there any alternatives that can help me getting the chat better ?

Comment: If you're using a native mobile app, you could use a Push Notification service when new chat messages come in: http://urbanairship.com/products/push-notifications/